# Restart a Windows CE device using FTP

Tags: c#, ftp, windows-ce

I am sending files to a Windows CE device using C# and FTP. When the transfer is complete, I need to restart the device.

Is it possible to restart a Windows CE device using FTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ftp does not allow you to send such commands, telnet, ssh or RDP is what you might want to consider using.

Comment: +1. @user2464801 - if FTP is the only available protocol you may have code on a device that waits for some specific file to be uploaded and trigger reset at that point.

Comment: What FTP-server are you using? Some servers provide this functionalities for example [pureftpd for linux](http://www.linuxbyexamples.net/2012/10/config-ftp-server-trigger-upload-file-to-call-external-script.html)

Comment: Not exactly. There's SITE command that sometimes allows extension commands including shell commands to be executed. Depends on the server of course.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem.  It turns out there is some existing software on the device from Motorola that allows me to restart it remotely.